# Select max date per year

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery, max

I have the table as follows:

```
user_id  date
1        2020-11-15
1        2020-10-15
1        2020-09-15
1        2019-12-15
1        2019-11-15
2        2020-11-15
2        2020-10-15
2        2019-12-15
3        2020-10-15
3        2020-09-15
```

And I'd like to select the max date for every year per user, so the result would be like:

```
user_id  date
1        2020-11-15
1        2019-12-15
2        2020-11-15
2        2019-12-15
3        2020-10-15
```

Some help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use aggregation:

```
select user_id, max(date)
from t
group by user_id, date_trunc('year', date);
```

If you have more columns that you want, then use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (user_id, date_trunc('year', date)) t.*
from t
order by user_id, date_trunc('year', date), date desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
Select t.*
  From your_table t
 Where not exists (select 1 from your_table tt 
                    Where t.id = tt.id
                      And date_trunc('year', t.date) = date_trunc('year', tt.date)
                      And tt.date > t.date)
```

Or you can use `row_number` analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by t.id, date_trunc('year', t.date) 
                          order by t.date desc) as rn
  From your_table t) t
Where rn = 1
```